# Group by multiples keys in python itertools in dict

Tags: python

I have this function def `group_by_transaction`, and I want it to return me a new list of dictionaries, but when I run it with my example data I get:

```
[{'user_id': 'user3',
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'transaction_amount_sum': 500},
 {'user_id': 'user4',
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'transaction_amount_sum': 500},
 {'user_id': 'user5',
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'transaction_amount_sum': 300}]
```

But I wish it was:

```
[{'number_of_users': 3,
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'transaction_amount_sum': 1300}]
```

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


data = [{'transaction_id': '00004ed8-2c57-4374-9a0c-3ff1d8a94a9e',
  'date': '2013-12-30',
  'user_id': 'user3',
  'is_blocked': 'false',
  'transaction_amount': 200,
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'is_active': '0'},
 {'transaction_id': '00004ed8-2c57-4374-9a0c-3ff1d8a94a7e',
  'date': '2013-12-21',
  'user_id': 'user3',
  'is_blocked': 'false',
  'transaction_amount': 300,
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'is_active': '0'},
       {'transaction_id': '00004ed8-2c57-4374-9a0c-3ff1d8a94a9e',
  'date': '2013-12-30',
  'user_id': 'user4',
  'is_blocked': 'false',
  'transaction_amount': 200,
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'is_active': '0'},
 {'transaction_id': '00004ed8-2c57-4374-9a0c-3ff1d8a94a7e',
  'date': '2013-12-21',
  'user_id': 'user4',
  'is_blocked': 'false',
  'transaction_amount': 300,
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'is_active': '0'},
 {'transaction_id': '00004ed8-2c57-4374-9a0c-3ff1d8a94a7e',
  'date': '2013-12-21',
  'user_id': 'user5',
  'is_blocked': 'false',
  'transaction_amount': 300,
  'transaction_category_id': '698723',
  'is_active': '0'}]


def group_by_transaction(data):
    grouper = ['user_id', 'transaction_category_id']
    key = itemgetter(*grouper)
    data.sort(key=key)
    return [{**dict(zip(grouper, k)), 'transaction_amount_sum': sum(map(itemgetter('transaction_amount'), g))} 
        for k, g in groupby(data, key=key)]


group_by_transaction(data)
```

Can anybody help me please?
I tried to add a new column into the calculation in the loop but I couldn't achieve any way

Comment: Why are you sorting/grouping on `user_id`, when, according to your own example, you want to group multiple different users into a single unified value?

Comment: Why is `'transaction_amount_sum'` mapped to a value of 500 in the output? You have two different values among those dictionaries.

Comment: I was trying to bring it into the loop but it didnt workout

Answer (score 1):

### Collect data with groupby

1. I'm not brave enough to do implicit data conversion inside a function. So I prefer to use `sorted(data)` instead of `data.sort`
2. You have to count somehow the number of unique users in order to get the key-value pair `{'number_of_users': 3}`
3. You're grouping by `['user_id', 'transaction_category_id']` pair, but to get what you wish the only key to group by is `'transaction_category_id'`

With that said, here's a code that I'm sure is close enough to yours to produce the desired grouping.

```py
def group_by_transaction(data):
    category = itemgetter('transaction_category_id') 
    user_amount = itemgetter('user_id', 'transaction_amount')
    return [
        {
            'transaction_category_id': cat_id
            , 'number_of_users': len({*users})
            , 'transaction_amount_sum': sum(amounts)
        }
        for cat_id, group in groupby(sorted(data, key=category), category)
        for users, amounts in [zip(*(user_amount(record) for record in group))]
    ]
```

### Update

About `for users, amounts in [zip(*(user_amount(record) for record in group))]`:

- by `user_amount(record) ...` we extract pairs of data `(user_id, transaction_amount)`
- by `zip(*(...))` we accomplish transposing of collected data
- `zip` is a generator, which in this case will result in two rows, where first is user_id values and second is transaction_amount values. To get them both at once we wrap zip-object as the only item of a list. That's the meaning of `[zip(...)]`
- when assigning zip not to one but to several variables, like in `users, amounts = zip(...)`, zipped values will be unpacked. In our case that's two rows mentioned above.

Comment: `for users, amounts in [zip(*(user_amount(gr) for gr in group))]` is pretty unreadable if you aren't familiar with Python tricks, why not just use a for-loop to create the intermediate variables?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I completely agree. On the other hand, the author has demonstrated a willingness to work with groupby and tricky list comprehensions. Therefore, I could not deny myself the pleasure of using this trick to make it similar in structure to the code in OP.

Comment: Fair enough! Fair enough. Might I just suggest using `[ ... ]` instead of `list(<gen-exp>)` Upvoted anyway.